# Counting polygons intersecting with each others in the same Vector layers

Tags: qgis, sql, query

I am currently working on some line string data that are very close by and have the same Start and endpoints for the most part. I want to create midpoints or average centroids that will tell me how many of those are grouped up close by.

Using mainly SQL queries i have been able to confirm that the centroids are close enough to intersect with each other using a 15 meter buffer, it is functionnal so far.

```
SELECT

feeder_NRO02.ca_pk_uid AS ID,
ST_centroid(feeder_NRO02.geom) AS geom,
1 AS count

FROM 
feeder_NRO02
```

My issue is that so far, I haven't been able to count how many times those buffers intersect with each other or create an average centroid.

Any advice? I have QGIS and some basic database tools at my disposal for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A test using SpatiaLite. Here `line` is an input Line layer and the buffer size is set to 15.

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM line AS a
WHERE st_intersects(st_buffer(st_centroid(a.geom), 15), st_buffer(st_centroid(a.geom), 15))
```

which will return only counts how many times those buffers intersect with each other.

If a list of such intersecting pairs is required:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id, count(*)
FROM   line a, line b 
WHERE  a.id < b.id  AND  st_within(st_centroid(a.geom), st_buffer(st_centroid(b.geom), 15)) = 1
GROUP BY a.id, b.id
```

In the above example I have used `st_within` to identify the distance between the centroids so probably this is not a direct answer.

[image]

Comment: This is a good start and will help a lot, i'm using this to improve my process and i'll post some updates once i start finding some clearer awnsers.

Thanks again!

Comment: By enlarging the buffer and counting/grouping by only for "a.id" 's it actually works. I have a lot of points to delete but it works.

Comment: @MoreauColin Great! Thanks for your feedback. Grouping only by "a.id" is nice idea.